# How to simplify vector expression with tensor product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm dealing with physical simulation and in order to increase performance I try to avoid the use of Matrix types in all expression where it's possible and have a sense. For instance, if I have the next expression  $R=(E-\vec{N} \otimes \vec{N}) \vec{n}$ as a part of some biggest expression. $E$ is an identy matrix. $\vec{N}$ and $\vec{n}$ is vectors columns. I may do the next
$$\vec{R}=(E-\vec{N} \otimes \vec{N}) \vec{n} = \vec{n} - \vec{N}* \vec{N}^\intercal* \vec{n}=\vec{n}-\vec{N}(\vec{N},\vec{n})=....$$ and so on. Eventually such transformations allowed me to get really simple final formula.
But now I faced the next expression
$$(((\vec{p}\times\vec{N})\otimes\vec{N})\times\vec{q})*\vec{n}$$
The only transformation I can do is
$$(((\vec{p}\times\vec{N})*\vec{N}^\intercal)\times\vec{q})*\vec{n}$$
Can anybody advise me, how can I simplify this expression further (in particular is it possible to form a dot product from $\vec{N}^\intercal$ and something else vector)? In other words, is it possible to write this expression only in the terms of cross and dot products? $$$$
NOTE: in this expression there is cross product of the matrix and vector. Result of such operation  $A\times\vec{b}$ is the matrix, where each row is a cross product of matrix $A$ row and vector $\vec{b}$.